# How can i call service every 1 second and check the response with angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, polling

I have a service implemented as below,

```
export class UploadPollingService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private appConfig: AppConfigService) { }
    checkUploadInfo(term: string, ): Observable<Event[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.appConfig.getAPIUrl() + `/checkStatus?processId=${term}`)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }
```

I am using this inside a component, and i want to call this service every 1 second and check status, basically do a polling. how to do?

```
this.uploadPollingService.checkUploadInfo()
```

Comment: you can use `timeinterval` method of javascript and call you function every second

Comment: like this? setInterval(checkUploadInfo(), 500);

Comment: yes, just like this, this will call your method every second, or after time provided by you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to use your service method within `timeinterval` like this

```
   ngOnInit(){
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.checkUpdate();
    }, 1000);
   }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
   }

  checkUpdate(){
    this.uploadPollingService.checkUploadInfo()
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res, "Response here");
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
  ....



  export class UploadPollingService {
    constructor(private http: Http, private appConfig: AppConfigService) { }
    checkUploadInfo(term?: string): Observable<Event[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.appConfig.getAPIUrl() + `/checkStatus?processId=${term}`)
            .map( res => {
              return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
            })
            .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of **this.uploadPollingService.checkUploadInfo()** use below code:

```
   interval: any;
   ngOnInit(){
   this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.uploadPollingService.checkUploadInfo() ;
    }, 1000);
   }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.interval) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
   }
```

Hope it's help!!!

Comment: how do i get the response?

Comment: you should use **.then** to read the response like   **this.uploadPollingService.checkUploadInfo().then(t => // your response)**;

Comment: @faceturn please check my answer.

Comment: If there is no subscribe how can we get the response?